# Bootstrap Grid allows Vertical Scroll

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, overflow

I have designed a "Coming Soon" template which has just one little issue. I have recently discover that the Bootstrap Grid in this template allows "Vertical Scroll" and it just doesn't make sense to me. I have noticed that it is in the First Part <!-- PART1 --> and do not know how to prevent it. 
I have applied CSS overflow-x: hidden (deleted it for demonstration), but I still really want to fix it. Scrolling with pressed mouse wheel (to the right) is still possible, please try.

[DEMO HERE](http://www.dailycube.de/themes/productx).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean horizontal scroll?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean horizontal scroll. The issue is you don't have a `.container` element in PART 1 which causes the `.row` (with a default margin of -15px on the sides) to grow outside of the window, you can either add a container element to your markup or add this to your CSS to remove the negative margins:

```
#home > .row {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Sidenote: you may want to remove the left padding from the countdown list `ul.cd` to have it center correctly